# elasticsearch NEST client, filed with attribute "not_analyzed" still be analyzed when search keywords contains hyphen

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a class named "IndexModel":

```
public class IndexModel
{
    [ElasticProperty(Index= FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Store = true)]
    public string ModelNumber{ get; set; }
}
```

following is how i setup the elastic client:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
var config = new ConnectionSettings(uri);
var client = new ElasticClient(config);
client.Map<IndexModel>(m => m.MapFromAttributes());
```

I can see the mapped result from response:

```
Request {
"indexmodel": {
"properties": {

  "modelNumber": {
    "type": "string",
    "store": true,
    "index": "not_analyzed"
     },
    }
  }
}
```

and i have one index record for this type, the value of "ModelNumber" property is "test-123", and following is my query:

```
var result = client.Search<IndexModel>(s => s.Query(new TermQuery() { Field = Property.Path<IndexModel>(it => it.ModelNumber), Value = "test-123"}));
```

here is the final mapped request i got:

```
Method: POST, 
Url: http://localhost:9200/_search, 
Request: {
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "modelNumber": {
        "value": "test-123"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But i can not get the result, if i change the value of "ModelNumber" property to "test123", re-index it, and search it by keywords "test123", then it's works, so i think the analyzer still analyzed the "ModelNumber" property, can someone help me, thanks.

Comment: i do have similar issue, after upgrading to latest NEST package. @Dragon do you have luck?

Comment: Is this issue solved?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, the solution is first create the index then put the mapping and at last add your data.

Add Type Attribute to your model field

```
 [ElasticProperty(OmitNorms = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]

        var node = new Uri("http://192.168.0.56:9200/");
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node, defaultIndex: "ticket");
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var createIndexResult = client.CreateIndex("ticket");
        var mapResult = client.Map<TicketElastic>(c => c.MapFromAttributes().IgnoreConflicts().Type("TicketElastic").Indices("ticket"));
```